# Vimperator - using tab key with firebug

Tags: firebug, conflict, shortcut, vimperator

Anyone know how to get round the fact that you can't tab through styles in firebug when vimperator is enabled? It jumps you down to the status bar instead of tabbing to the next property.

I've tried adding:

```
  noremap <Tab> <nop>
```

to my .vimperatorrc  ..  no luck

Comment: i've just discoverd you can switch across from the attribute to the value using ':' and you can get to the next line using <return> so thats cool..  BUT still not as nice as just tabbing through the whole thing..  and improvements on that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use enter instead of tab. Enter works both for going from the attribute to the value (as does ":", as you noted yourself), and for going to the next line. I agree it's not perfect, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

On osx, running mavericks, I have the same issue. Im not sure of an actual solution, but this appears to only occur for me when I'm running firebug as a docked window (ex. attached to the main window at the bottom). If you run firebug in it's own window (click on the up arrow at the top right of the default firebug menubar), the problem does not occur.

I was previously using the above solution as a last ditch effort, then realized there didn't seem to be a workaround for shift+tab or reverse iterative jump (deal breaker).